# Nginx rewriting URL with params to url without params

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

So I have this URL: `/web/cms.php?open=unsereteam`

I want to redirect to: `https://www.camper-center.ch/portrait/unser-team.html`

I tried this:

```
rewrite ^/web/cms.php?open=unsereteam$ https://www.camper-center.ch/portrait/unser-team.html permanent;
```

and this:

```
if ($args ~* "/web/cms.php?open=unsereteam") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/portrait/unser-team.html? last;
}
```

doesnt work...

Thanks to Ivan Shatsky it worked with:

```
if ($request_uri = "/web/cms.php?open=unsereteam") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/portrait/unser-team.html? last;
}
```

---

If I have more than one param like

```
if ($request_uri = "/web/listing.php?monat=03&jahr=2018") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=03&year=2018? last;
}
```

Im triying something like:

```
if ($arg_monat = "02" & $arg_jahr="2020") { 
    rewrite ^/web/cms\.php$ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=02&year=2020? last;
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work too.

Maybe you have a Solution for this too?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Im trying something like this:

```
if ($arg_monat && $arg_jahr ) {
    rewrite ^/web/listing\.php$ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=$arg_monat&year=$arg_jahr? last;
}
```

in the end I want the first url to redirect to the second:

/web/listing.php?monat=02&jahr=2020

to

/news/aktuell.html?month=02&year=2020

Answer (score 1):

As being told a thousand times, both `rewrite` and `location` directives works with the *normailzed* URI which **does not include** the query part of the request, but only the `/web/cms.php` for your case. The `$args` variable contains the query part of the request (`open=unsereteam` for your case). It is a `$request_uri` that contains the full request URI in its original state. You can use

```
if ($request_uri = "/web/cms.php?open=unsereteam") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/portrait/unser-team.html? last;
}
```

or for case insensitive comparsion

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^/web/cms\.php\?open=unsereteam") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.camper-center.ch/portrait/unser-team.html? last;
}
```

but it won't match if your request would have, lets say, some additional query argument before the `open` one. The better one is

```
if ($arg_open = "unsereteam") { # or ($arg_open ~* "^unsereteam$") for case insensitive check
    # do the rewrite only on '/web/cms.php' URI
    rewrite ^/web/cms\.php$ https://www.camper-center.ch/portrait/unser-team.html? last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I was searching years. The first solution works perfectly.. now if I have more than one parameter like
/web/listing.php?monat=02&jahr=2020
to
https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=02&year=2020
how do I handle this?

Comment: @DomenicoSanfilippo I suggest you to use the last solution, it is more reliable. You are trying to use Apache-style solutions, it is a bad practice dealing with nginx. What should happened if your `/web/listing.php` request will have only one parameter? More that two parameters? Can you specify some ruleset you want to be used?

Comment: look edit above

Comment: Im trying something like this:

if ($arg_monat && $arg_jahr ) {
    rewrite ^/web/listing\.php$ https://www.camper-center.ch/news/aktuell.html?month=$arg_monat&year=$arg_jahr? last;
}
in the end I want the first url to redirect to the second:

/web/listing.php?monat=02&jahr=2020

to

/news/aktuell.html?month=02&year=2020